# How to download and install IBM Lotus Sametime Connect 8.5.2 on Ubuntu 13.04 64bit

Tags: 13.04, software-installation, 64-bit, ibm

Where can I get IBM Lotus Sametime Connect 8.5.2 for 64-bit Ubuntu 13.04 and how to install it?

Comment: Thanks! Can you edit this so that it is in the form of a question and an answer to your own question?

Comment: Yes, my article (on matt-helps.com) is a touch old - glad you got it working.

Comment: Thanks for posting this but please put this in a q&a form: create a question and answer it. You can then accept your answer so everyone knows it has an answer.

Comment: Done; I changed the question to a real question, and provided the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are instructions on how to download and install IBM's sametime on a 64-bit Ubuntu:

1. download sametime-setup-linux.zip from

   "http://sametime.dpteruel.es/sametime/network-install/applet/index_en.html?lang=en"

   which will detect your OS and send you the appropriate installation zip file
2. unzip to get an rpm package
3. get "alien" package conversion program, like so:

   > sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
4. try converting the rpm to deb with alien like so:

   > sudo alien --scripts --verbose sametime-connect-8.5.2-20110516.2011.i586.rpm

   that didn't work for me, if it works for you then you will get a deb package 
   and you can install it the usual way.
5. I got an error saying

   > the package is for architecture i386 ; the package cannot be built on this system

   my system is an amd64 (aka x64) architecture.
   So I found instructions here

   http://www.matt-helps.com/using-alien-to-convert-rpm-packages-to-lpia-deb/

   which led me to run the following:

   > sudo alien --verbose -g sametime-connect-8.5.2-20110516.2011.i586.rpm
   >
   > cd sametime-connect-8.5.2
   >
   > sudo ./debian/rules binary

Note: the last command is supposed to generate a debian package but it didn't, 
      it just copied stuff around. You can also modify the debian/control file and change the target architecture before running ./debian/rules

1. since I still had no debian package and I noticed that the sametime files are all in ./opt/ibm/ and one executable in ./usr/bin

   I simply moved them as follows:

   > mv ./opt/ibm /opt/.
   >
   > mv ./usr/bin/sametime-connect /usr/bin/.
2. I ran /usr/bin/sametime-connect and voilà it worked, it asked me for the license agreement and opened the sametime.

Answer (score 1):

You can download **sametime-connect-8.5.2-20110516.2011.i386.deb** file from:

http://theweeks.org/tmp/FILES/ST-8.5.2_GA/Linux/

So no need to use alien.

Comment: This file does work. The instructions by wael will vary by distro.